# Call function with another uint type

Tags: solidity

I would like to know what is happening under the hood when I call a function which uses normally receive a `uint256` as argument, but with another `uint` type, for example `uint8`.

I have the impression that there is no error.

For example:

```
function sqrt(uint256 y) public pure returns (uint256) {
    if (y > 3) {
        uint256 z = y;
        uint256 x = y / 2 + 1;
        while (x < z) {
            z = x;
            x = (y / x + x) / 2;
        }
        return z;
    } else if (y != 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function sqrtTest(uint8 y) public pure returns (uint256) {
    return sqrt(y);
}
```

Here when I call `sqrtTest` with 4, it works.

Is there a reason why I should avoid this type of operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace the input `uint256` parameter type to a smaller one, the function will only accept the largest value of the type.

Example:

```
function sqrt(uint8 y) public pure returns (uint256) {
```

The largest value of `uint8` is `255`.

When you try to pass `256`, the function call throws an `out-of-bounds` exception. And since this exception is not handled, the call reverts.

Comment: But the casting from uint8 to uint256 happens seamlessly?

Comment: @Jundiaius Yes. When you cast from a smaller to larger type, it works seamlessly (at least in the current version, 0.8). On the low-level, it just adds the leading/trailing (depending on the datatype) zeros.